# Accessing array from inside multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, expo

I am trying to access this array.  I have a state with multiple objects in it, and each object's results have multiple arrays.  I am trying to dynamically display the arrays on some pdf markup.  I need the base64 information only

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: "base64"
1: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGwAABBACAYAAAAiFe8LAAABd
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: (2) ['width', 2156]
2: (2) ['uri', 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…ipulator/6295EECB-4B54-4742-9F57-F426648EF12F.png']
3: (2) ['height', 4160]
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

This is what I have tried and also am trying to dynamically display the images.

```
   const test = Object.entries(allImages);
    const newTest = test.map((img) => img);
    console.log(newTest);

    const displayImage = () => {
      let t = "";
      for (let i in newTest) {
        const item = newTest[i];
        t =
          t +
          `<tr>
            <td>    
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${item}"
               style="width: 40vw;" />
            </td>
        </tr>`;
      }
      return t;
    };
```

JSON.stringify(allImages) returns times the number of images I have taken, in this case 3 base64 images

```
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGwA....
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGwA....
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGwA....
```

update::

```
[{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAGCCAYAAACl7IwgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAA}]
```

```
 const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);

  const handleMultiImages = () => {
    form.morePictures.map(async (images) => {
      const multiAsset = Asset.fromModule(`${images.morePictures}`);
      const multiImage = await manipulateAsync(
        multiAsset.localUri ?? multiAsset.uri,
        [{ resize: { width: 200 } }],
        {
          base64: true,
          compress: 0.5,
          format: SaveFormat.PNG,
        }
      );
      setAllImages([multiImage]);
    });
  };
```

form.morePictures

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {morePictures: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…S/Camera/FF9315E0-8408-466C-AF88-230A93346327.jpg'}
1: {morePictures: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…S/Camera/85A49B42-A7ED-45C6-A6C1-A96852CAE9FC.jpg'}
2: {morePictures: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…S/Camera/2E3EBE8A-CCD3-4484-9B37-F1C7D91EC8FF.jpg'}
3: {morePictures: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…S/Camera/4F16D28F-957F-476D-BE24-2F2A6F00149D.jpg'}
4: {morePictures: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/212…S/Camera/6C61B57E-9C60-43E3-BEBD-03014C442D8E.jpg'}
length: 5
```

JSON.stringify(multiImage) shows as an object

```
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAGCCAYAAACl7IwgA"}
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAGCCAYAAACl7alkdfja"}
{"base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAGCCAYAAACl7Iadfaf"}
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `JSON.stringify(allImages)`?

Comment: Just updated my question. It shows base64 key: value

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following code will do what you want.

```js
    const displayImage = () => {
      return allImages.map(image => (
        `<tr>
           <td>    
             <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${image.base64}" style="width: 40vw;" />
           </td>
         </tr>`
      )).join('\n');
    };
```

Explanation: you already have the data in an array, and you want to turn that array into something else. `.map` is built for this. Each array member is an object with the key `base64` and the value of the image.

I think there might be some misunderstandings of objects, arrays, and their associated methods. When you write `for (let i in newTest) {`, `i` will be an array member, not a number; try logging it out. Also, `for...of` is safer; `in` can contain extra properties.

`Object.entries` technically works on arrays since arrays are just objects with numerical keys in JS, but it's not meant for that. It's meant for objects with named keys. `Object.entries({ a: 1, b: 2 })` will give you `[[ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ]]`.

I recommend reading the following things:

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: I see what you are talking about,  I just tried but I get allImages.map is not a function.   I feel as though this is at least the right track to be on.    I will read all of the following as well

Comment: Can you try running it through JSON.stringify again? What you pasted before doesn't totally make sense, so I assumed it was the contents of an array without the brackets, which is my fault. If you can post it exactly as it comes out, I'll revise my answer to match it.

Comment: so what I ended up doing is setting my state like this   setAllImages([multiImage]);  and now I can map through, but it only maps through the first and last image.  I'll update question as well and show you the image manipulator function that I have to use to turn into a base64.  I've been stuck on this for 2 days: updated!

Comment: What does `JSON.stringify(multiImage)` look like? If I can understand the shape of the data, I can help

Comment: Updated,  it shows up as an object

Comment: I'm confused, that's not an object or an array. Each thing in curly braces is an object, but all together, they don't represent a data type. Is there anything you're editing out of the console log?

Comment: yea,  I'm at a total loss too

Comment: Can you make an expo snack or repo with this issue? I would like to look at the code

Comment: I actually figured it out...  I think it's a hacky way, but yes I will.  Maybe you can give me some recommendations on refactoring it

Comment: Sure, happy to take a look